Problem with TypeScript generic interface method
I'm trying to create inteface with generic method. I don't know how to specify generic type when using it in list of objects.
export type Data = Array<object>
export interface Column {
    name: string
    index: string
    columns?: Column[]
    formatter?: <T>(cell: T) => T
}

export const listOfEmployeesColumns: Column[] = [
    {
        name: "Salary",
        index: "salary",
        formatter: (cell: number) =>  cell * 0.23
    },
    {
        name: "Hire date",
        index: "hire_date",
        formatter: (cell: string) =>  cell.replace("-", "/")
    }
]

export const listOfEmployees = [
    {
        "salary": 7000,
        "hire_date": "2020-01-15"
    },
    {
        "salary": 11000
        "hire_date": "2018-07-01"
    }
]

const Table = (
    { rows, columns, index = false, handleCreate = undefined }:
        { rows: Data, columns: Column[], index?: boolean, handleCreate?: () => void }
) => {
    return {columns.map(column => {
       return column.formatter !== null ? <td>column.formatter(rows[column.index])</td> : <td>rows[column.index]</td>
    })
}

<Table 
    rows={listOfEmployees} 
    columns={listOfEmployeesColumns}
/>

In this case I got this error:
Type '(cell: string) => string' is not assignable to type '<T>(cell: T) => T'.
Types of parameters 'cell' and 'cell' are incompatible.
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'.

How to specify generic type of formatter method of Column interface in list of Column objects

export interface Column<T>

@SaniHuttunen Is this the only solution?

That is the only way to define what you asked for: a generic interface.

• Please [edit] this code to be a [mre]. The actual error you get with <string>(cell: string) => ... is that string cannot be the name of a type parameter. It's not clear what you're trying to do there, so maybe just remove that whole piece? Don't use string as the name of a generic type parameter. • What is the use case? If you have a value of type Column, what can you do with the formatter property when you don't know T? I could imagine a tree structure that represents a column and its nested children, but that's complex. Please [edit] to explain how you intend to use this type.

@jcalz I edit the question. I think is more clear now

You've removed the problematic generic, but I still don't understand the use case. Given listOfEmployeesColumns of type Column[], what can you do to it? How can you use the formatter methods? How do you know what parameter types they take? What happens if I call listOfEmployeesColumns.map(x => x.formatter?.(null))? You get runtime errors, because null isn't a valid argument for either formatter. But how is TS supposed to know that? What's the use case here?

@jcalz It's used to change value in generation of cell value in table. cell value can't be null. It;s value from data passed to table:
const Table = (     { rows, columns, index = false, handleCreate = undefined }:         { rows: Data, columns: Column[], index?: boolean, handleCreate?: () => void } )

You say it can't be null but right now there's no code that implies that anywhere.  In your example in the comment, what type is Data? That's going to be the key to defining Column, since apparently it depends on it. Please [edit] to make the code a [mre] which shows how it works. It should make it obvious how mixed/nested data is actually consumed.

@jcalz I edit it again

Hmm, so I'd say you really want Column to be generic in the type of rows elements, as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz I would like to have only formatter method as generic not Column. It's possible?

It doesn’t make any sense for the method to be generic. Generic methods let the caller choose the generic type argument, not the implementer. So not only isn’t it possible, but it’s not clear what you even mean by that. Furthermore, doesn’t index have a bearing on what type formatter accepts? It really seems like you need type parameter information at the scope of Column and not just the formatter method.  Can you look at my playground link from my previous comment and let me know if it works as you’re expecting or not?

@jcalz yes this example is correct

The only way this could work is if Column is generic in the type T of the data it represents (the parameter type and the return value of formatter). You don't want formatter to be a generic method. That would mean callers can choose the type argument. Since you need the implementer to choose the type argument, that means Column itself needs to be generic.
Additionally, according to your use case, it is also essentially generic in the type K of the index property, since that property must match up with a key of the relevant data... and T must the property type at that key.
With this in mind, here's a possible definition for Column:
interface Column<K extends PropertyKey, T> {
    name: string
    index: K
    columns?: T extends object ? readonly ColumnForProps<T>[] : never;
    formatter?: (cell: T) => T
}

type ColumnForProps<T extends object> =
    { [K in keyof T]-?: Column<K, T[K]> }[keyof T]

Note that this is effectively a recursive definition. The columns property is a conditional type. If the type T is itself an object, then columns should be an array of Column objects for each property of T.  (I'm using a readonly array, which is more permissive than a mutable array.) If T is not an object then columns is an optional property of the impossible never type, meaning that if T isn't an object, you shouldn't have a defined columns property for Column<K, T>.
The type ColumnForProps<T> is a distributive object type (as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109) which becomes the union of Column<K, T[K]> for each K in keyof T. So if T is {a: A, b: B}, then ColumnForProps<T> is Column<"a", A> | Column<"b", B>.

That also means Table must be generic in the type T of the elements of the rows property, like this:
const Table = <T extends object>(
    { rows, columns, index = false, handleCreate = undefined }: {
        rows: readonly T[],
        columns: readonly ColumnForProps<T>[],
        index?: boolean,
        handleCreate?: () => void
    }
) => (null!); // <-- not worried about implementation

Note that I've removed the implementation since we don't care about it here, and the real implementation should presumably be recursive, and I don't want to digress.
So, when you call Table, TypeScript should infer T from the element type of the rows property, and then use it to require that columns is an array of ColumnForProps<T> objects.
Let's test that out:
const listOfEmployeesColumns = [
    {
        name: "Salary",
        index: "salary",
        formatter: (cell: number) => cell * 0.23
    },
    {
        name: "Hire date",
        index: "hire_date",
        formatter: (cell: string) => cell.replace("-", "/")
    }
] as const;

const listOfEmployees = [
    {
        "salary": 7000,
        "hire_date": "2020-01-15"
    },
    {
        "salary": 11000,
        "hire_date": "2018-07-01"
    }
];

<Table
    rows={listOfEmployees} // okay
    columns={listOfEmployeesColumns} // okay
/>

That works without error. Note that I had to use a const assertion on the initializer for listOfEmployeesColumns, in order for TypeScript to keep track of the literal types of the index properties. Otherwise TypeScript would infer string which isn't enough information to verify that listOfEmployeesColumns matches listOfEmployees.
If we write the list inline then we don't need a const assertion because TypeScript knows to pay attention to the literal types of index:
<Table
    rows={listOfEmployees}
    columns={[
        {
            name: "Salary",
            index: "salary",
            formatter(cell) { return cell - 1 }
        },
        {
            name: "Hire date",
            index: 'hire_date',
            formatter(cell) { return cell.toUpperCase() }
        }
    ]}
/>

You can see that TypeScript will complain if you try to use an index it doesn't expect:
<Table
    rows={listOfEmployees}
    columns={[
        { name: "Salary", index: "salary" },
        { name: "Hire date", index: 'hire_date' },
        { name: "Oops", index: 'oops' } // error!
        //              ~~~~~ <-- Type '"oops"' is not 
        // assignable to type '"salary" | "hire_date"'.
    ]}
/>

Or if you give it a bad formatter:
<Table
    rows={listOfEmployees}
    columns={[
        { name: "Salary", index: "salary" },
        {
            name: "Hire date", index: 'hire_date',
            formatter(cell: number) { return cell + 1 }
        }, // error!
        // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        // Types of property 'formatter' are incompatible.
    ]}
/>

That should hopefully justify the need for Column to be generic in the type of index also, since it is precisely that property which governs the expected type of formatter.
Finally, because Column is recursive, let's see what happens if rows contains nested objects:
<Table
    rows={[{ a: { b: "abc" } }, { a: { b: "def" } }]}
    columns={[
        {
            index: "a", name: "A", columns: [
                { index: "b", name: "B", formatter(cell) { return cell.toLowerCase() } }
            ]
        }
    ]}
/>

Looks good. The type of the rows elements is {a: {b: string}}, and you can see that TypeScript expects the columns property of the index: "a" element to be an index: "b" column, where formatter expects and returns a string value.
Playground link to code

You are not defining a generic interface.
It should be something like:
export interface Column<T> {
    name: string
    index: string
    columns?: Column<T>[]
    formatter?: (cell: T) => T
}

export const listOfEmployeesColumns: Column<string>[] = [
    {
        name: "Hire date",
        index: "hire_date",
        formatter: (cell: string) =>  cell.replace("-", "/")
    }
]


It will work, But i have mixed types in this list and also nested Column can be other types. I would like to make only the method to by generic

That cannot be done. What you could do is make all "mixed types" inherit from the same base class and use the base class as the generic type. But that is not always possible if the types are too different.
